# Blazor server-side application api request issue httpClient.PostAsync IHttpClientFactory

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am developing a Blazor server-side application.

The api call generates and downloads a pdf file.

No error is displayed on the client side but I can see from the server logs that the API call is not being processed. The only error message I can identify is StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: Unsupported Media Type, Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers.

GetAsync is working fine 
var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"xxx/yyyyy/zzzzz");
The only significant issue I have for now is with serialisation and deserialisation using the new System.Text.Json.Serialization and for now I have worked around this by developing my own serialisation and deserialisation routines which work fine and I will use them until I have resolved the issues with System.Text.Json.Serialization.

My question relates to PostAsynch which I cannot get to work. I am using Basic Authentication for now and sending a JSON body. I am calling APIs which are live and have been working fine with other applications calling them. They also work fine in Postman, I just cannot get them to work with Blazor.

```
//The relevant Startup code is as follows

            services.AddHttpClient<Services.ApiServicerw>(client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com");
            });

//The code in the .razor page is as follows

@page "/runreport2"

@using BlazorApp1.Services
@inject ApiServicerw ApiService1

@using System.IO

<h1>Report</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates running a report</p>

@code {  
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
    var fresult = await ApiService1.GetContactsAsync(); 
    }
}

//An extract of the code in the Services class is as follows

          _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
           System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", encoded);
            var stringContent = new StringContent(jsonString);
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
         System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync($"api/xxxx/yyyyyy",stringContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this. I needed to change this line as follows

var stringContent = new StringContent(jsonString,System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");